# With python csv module, why does creating a list of identical values speed up creation of a list of rows?

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading a large csv file (more than 4 million rows) using the invaluable `csv` module in Python.  In timing various approaches, I've come across an unintuitive result.

If I run the following script it takes about **11-12 seconds**.  `b` is created almost instantly after `a`.

```
r = csv.reader(open("data.csv", "rb"), delimiter=";")
a = [None for row in r]
b = [row for row in r]
```

But if I run a similar script that doesn't create `a` at all, the code takes *longer* (**21-22 seconds**):

```
r = csv.reader(open("data.csv", "rb"), delimiter=";")
b = [row for row in r]
```

I can comprehend why the creation of `b` takes almost no time after `a` has already been created.  But I would have thought (naively) that the second code block, in which only `b` is created and not `a`, would be the faster script.  At the risk of appearing un-Pythonic, **I'm interested to know if anyone can explain why creating `a` and then `b` is almost twice as fast as creating `b` alone.**

Furthermore, if this speed boost is consistent across more complicated operations, are there good reasons (other than style/readibility concerns) *not* to take advantage of it?  Are savvier Python programmers than I already achieving the same time savings with some conventional method I've never heard of?

If I construct `a` using, say, an integer instead of `None`, I get the same result. If instead of iterating over a `csv.reader` object I iterate over `open("data.csv", "rb").readlines()`, the timing is as I expect it to be: creating `b` alone is faster than creating `a` then `b`.  So the time disparity presumably has something to do with the properties of a `csv.reader` object, or of a more general class of objects like it.  If I create `b` prior to `a`, the time is about the same as if I created `b` alone.

Some notes:

- Creating `b` prior to `a` takes the same time as creating `b` alone.
- I'm not running these line-by-line in interactive mode.  I'm running each as a separate script.
- I'm not really trying to create a list full of ones with the same length as `r`, or a list of the rows in `r`.
- In case it matters, I'm running Python 2.7.3, using the Enthought Python distribution 7.3-2, on 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at `b` in your first example? It's empty because `r` was exhausted by the first list comprehension. All rows have already been iterated over, and - as @soulcheck has pointed out - it's much faster to create a list of 4 million `None`s than a list that contains 4 million sublists.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which is why `a` is created quicker.

Comment: @LevLevitsky you mean why a list of 4 million Nones is created faster than a list containing 4 million row objects?

Comment: @soulcheck Yes, this is what the question is about. It's not really intuitive to me why it's so much faster: aren't the rows evaluated in both cases? I'm guessing they are, and the only difference is then that all the None's (or small ints) share the same pointer. I'd love to see an explanation in your answer, though, my guess can be wildly off as I know embarrassingly little about the implementation.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: I don't know about the implementation details either, but I would assume it has to do with memory allocation - reading 4 million rows into RAM (and storing them all) probably takes the Python interpreter longer than "overwriting" the same `row` 4 million times. But it's an interesting question.

Comment: That's a very sound idea. The credit for the question goes to the OP, I think I just rephrased the initial question.

Comment: Good point about the memory. There's probably a good bit of `malloc` going on. On Unix, you can look at the execution time of the process; lots of extra "system time" means the delay is due to system calls (like memory allocation), while extra user time means the time is just spent moving data around.

Answer (score 3):

This might give some insight. Let's take a short example of a csv file with 10 lines and compare this:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

r = csv.reader(open('foo.csv'))
a = [id(row) for row in r]

r = csv.reader(open('foo.csv'))
b = [row for row in r]
b_id = [id(row) for row in b]

c1 = Counter(a)
c2 = Counter(b_id)

print c1
print c2
```

This results in

```
Counter({139713821424456: 5, 139713821196512: 5})
Counter({139713821196512: 1, 139713821669136: 1, 139713821668776: 1, 139713821196584: 1, 139713821669064: 1, 139713821668560: 1, 139713821658792: 1, 139713821668704: 1, 139713821668848: 1, 139713821668632: 1})
```

In other words, in `a`, we reused the same memory over and over. Since the list comprehension for `a` does not retain any reference to the `row`, it will be garbage collected right away, opening that memory up for reuse.  If we hold onto it, naturally, we'll have to allocate memory for each new list.